# Importing data from csv into postgres - handling a one-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, relational-database

I have a postgres db with a table of `products` and `productCategories`.
Each `product` can have many `productCategories`.

They are joined by a table `products__product_categories` table, like the schema below:[image]

I have a csv of products that I want to import into my db (via pgadmin), I can successfully import the basic rows, but I'm lost on how to import the relation portion of the db, as per csv screenshot below, I have a productCategory column where a user can choose which categories should be linked.

Any pointers on what to look at for this would be much appreciated.

[image]